# Is it possible to use Data Annotations for MVC in an ASP.NET WEBFORM Business Object Class?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How can I use this convention in an asp.net WEBFORM Business object class?

Example In MVC

```
using System.ComponenModel.DataAnnotation;

public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5,20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set;}

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5,20)]
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

I want to use this data annotation in my asp.net webform businessobject class for client validation and server validation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately WebForms doesn't have native support of Data Annotations like MVC.

But you can use custom decisions:

1. [system componentmodel dataannotations for asp.net webforms](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2010/05/system-componentmodel-dataannotations-for-asp-net-web-forms/)
2. [Building an ASP.NET Validator Using Data Annotations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Data_Annotations_with_ASP.aspx)
3. [ASP.NET: WebForms Validation with Data Annotations](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html)