# What's the recommended way to collect input values in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: asp.net, mvp

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET application "by the book"; I have my Web Forms implement MVP pattern, my presenter talks only to Services layer that than talks to a bunch of repositories all sharing my own EF ObjectContext. So far so good. Now I'm tackling the front end and I have a dilemma...

Lets say I have an asp:TextBox control named txtDateOfBirth and submit button. When a user clicks the button, I need to send data from ASPX to presenter to Service to .... but the problem is that in the end I don't need String, but DateTime? and **I don't know the best place to make the conversion**:

- Should I put a validator in ASPX page and then in code-behind do the conversion?
- Or should I collect a bunch of strings from the form, create a request for the service containing only strings, and than have my Business Model do the try/convert and report errors?

What do you recommend? Any insight is appreciated...

**EDIT:** OK, after having read and tried all of your suggestions, I decided to go with the following:

1. Code-behind and APSX are responsible for data type conversions. I
   decided to go with simple CompareValidator and check for the
   appropriate type so code-behind can surely convert it.
2. Request that goes from presenter to service layer is appropriately
   typed.
3. All other validation is being done by business layer (including
   string lengths, required or not, range, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood that correctly, you have an textbox in your WebForm where the user writes something that should be a date, right?

There are somethings you can do:

- You can use a mask for the textbox, formated for your date format. That will send you a string back that looks like a date (check how later). I think asp:textbox have this option; anyway, MaskedEdit controls have it too: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx
- You can use a model class, then validate the input according to the Custom Decisions for the fields in that model. See here: [Is it possible to use Data Annotations for MVC in an ASP.NET WEBFORM Business Object Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971079/is-it-possible-to-use-data-annotations-for-mvc-in-an-asp-net-webform-business-ob)
- You can validate through Javascript in your WebForm, before sending it back. It is kind of messy, anyway.
- Or you can just validate that in your code-behind, and reload your page if something is wrong with an error message somewhere. It is what the DataAnnotations do automatically in MVC.

Comment: I don't think using Telerik is an option, and neither is writing JavaScript. But this option number two seems like something I've been looking for. OK, lets say I build validator, that's the easy part. Now the question is: what do I data annotate? I really don't like the idea of data annotating my business classes. Does it make sense to annotate the viewmodel that comes from the Service and is displayed in ASPX form?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it's legitimate for the presentation layer to convert primitive types into whatever the business layer wants to deal with.

For example in the ASP.NET MVC framework (I know you're not using it), the business layer communicates with the view layer using "models" which are simple, business specific .NET objects designed for communication the three MVC layers.

Comment: OK, that's a good start! So, when I go to Service layer, my request object will have the appropriate types. Now all that's left to do is to see how to convert strings into those types....

Answer (score 1):

1) Code-behind should do the conversion

- For example, input string (from txtDateOfBirth) to DateTime or DateTime?

2) Business logic should check the business rules

- For example, user must be 16 years or older

3) Method should be

- `InsertUser(User user) {}` or
- `InsertUser(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime or DateTime? dateOfBirth) {}`

You can see that .Net Framework uses mostly strongly type parameters instead of string and object.

If you do not want to pass nullable values, you can use the following approach which is used in  [DotNetNuke](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/).

```
public class Null
{    
    public static int NullInteger
    {
        get { return -1; }
    }    

    public static decimal NullDecimal
    {
        get { return decimal.MinValue; }
    }

    public static DateTime NullDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.MinValue; }
    }

    ...
}
```

**Edited** - As you requested, I added the code behind code. This is not really a pattern; it's just a person preference.

```
public string FirstName
{
  get { return FirstNameTextBox.Text; }
}

public string LastName
{
  get { return LastNameTextBox.Text; }
}

public DateTime DateOfBirth
{
  get
  {
    DateTime d;
    return DateTime.TryParse(DateOfBirthTextBox.Text, out d) ? 
      d : Null.NullDate;
  }
}

protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    var user = new Users()
    {
      FirstName = this.FirstName,
      LastName = this.LastName,
      DateOfBirth = this.DateOfBirth
    };
    UserService.InsertUser(user);
    ... 
  }
  Catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Log error
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I think it could be helped by showing a code-behind pattern for server-side validation (using tryparse?) and passing validation errors back to the page somehow (is it possible from server-side to give validation errors to ValidationSummary, for instance?)

Comment: I still prefer to use RequiredFieldValidators and other client-side validators in addition to business logic's valiation. Again, it is just personal preference. If you have question in validation, please create a new ticket, so that it'll be helpful to others too.